# Error:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal, server

```
$ch = curl_init();
$clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

this code working on localhost but when i am testing on my live server it will give me this error **Error:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure** then i tried this

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://tlstest.paypal.com/"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
if ($err = curl_error($ch)) {
var_dump($err);
echo "DEBUG INFORMATION:\n###########";
echo "CURL VERSION";
echo json_encode(curl_version(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}?>
```

github.com/paypal/TLS-update/tree/master/php this will again work on localhost and on live it gives me this

```
error bool(false)
string(67) "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to tlstest.paypal.com:443 "
DEBUG INFORMATION:
###########CURL VERSION
```

my server have these certificates

**Server Key and Certificate #1**

```
Subject *.secure.xxxxxxxx.com


Fingerprint SHA1: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


Pin SHA256: S4/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


Common names    *.secure.xxxxxxxx.com   MISMATCH


Alternative names   *.secure.xxxxxxx.com



Key RSA 2048 bits (e 65537)


Weak key (Debian)   No


Issuer  Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4


AIA: xxxxxxx/ss.crt


Signature algorithm SHA256withRSA


Extended Validation No


Certificate Transparency    Yes (certificate)


OCSP Must Staple    No


Revocation information  CRL, OCSP


CRL: xxxxxx/ss.crl


OCSP: xxxxxxxxx


Revocation status   Good (not revoked)

Trusted No   NOT TRUSTED (Why?)
```

**#2**

```
Subject Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4


Fingerprint SHA1: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


Pin SHA256: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


Key RSA 2048 bits (e 65537)


Issuer  VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5


Signature algorithm SHA256withRSA
```

**#3**

```
Subject VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5


Fingerprint SHA1: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


Pin SHA256: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Key RSA 2048 bits (e 65537)


Issuer  VeriSign, Inc. / Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority

Signature algorithm SHA1withRSA   WEAK

**Protocols**


TLS 1.2 Yes


TLS 1.1 Yes


TLS 1.0 Yes


SSL 3   No


SSL 2   No
```

[image]

**checked requirements [at](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1766&expand=true&locale=en_US)**

Comment: It might be due to an old curl/openssl version. Please add the relevant version information to your question. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-version.php.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich curl details http://i.stack.imgur.com/5tPfC.png and this is the response of function.curl-version.php **CURL_VERSION_IPV6 does not match CURL_VERSION_KERBEROS4 does not match CURL_VERSION_SSL matches CURL_VERSION_LIBZ matches**

Comment: In case you really want to get help make it easy for other to help you: i.e. use proper formatting and don't hide relevant information (like software versions) inside an image inside a comment. Remember: nobody is required to help you so just use cut+paste to enter the information as text into your original question.

Answer (score 3):

TL;TR: your software is too old to support these servers.

Both servers support TLS 1.2 only as can be seen when checking with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html). Your OpenSSL version is 1.0.0s which does not support TLS 1.2 yet. Support is only available since 1.0.1.

> my server have these certificates ...

The setup of your web server (i.e. certificates, TLS versions...) are not relevant because in this case you are the client connecting to some other server.

Answer (score 1):

Your server may support TLS 1.2, but you need to make sure the HTTP requests are actually using it.  Based on your result you're getting, you apparently are not using TLS 1.2 with the requests.

Try adding this to your cURL options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
```

That will force TLS 1.2.

Alternatively, get your server software stack updated and this will happen automatically.  See [this post](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vulnerability/) for more details, most importantly this part:

> If you want to use TLS 1.2 you’ll need to upgrade to OpenSSL 1.0.1 as a minimum, and then you’ll be able to set CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to 6 (TLS 1.2).
>
> If you want TLS 1.2 to be used automatically during SSL requests, you’ll also need to upgrade to PHP 5.5.19+ (this is the ideal solution but many projects are still on older PHP versions).

Comment: Well the error that you've posted specifically says that the request was made with sslv3, so the info you have about your server must not be correct.  This is a very common problem.  See [this post](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vulnerability/) for more details.

Comment: @AndrewAngell: openssl spits "sslv3 alert handshake failure" and similar errors on lots of places even if no SSL 3.0 is involved because it just happens in the code which handles SSL 3.+ (i.e. SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0...) messages. This is very irritating because there is often no sslv3 involved at all in the real messages.

Comment: I have never seen this error from PayPal when sslv3 wasn't being used.  It's a very specific error.

Comment: @AndrewAngell on my server i have SSL Version OpenSSL/1.0.0s as you can see http://i.stack.imgur.com/5tPfC.png

Comment: As it says in my answer, you need OpenSSL 1.0.1 as a minimum (which was released in 2012) in order for TLS 1.2 to work.  You need to update your server software stack.

Comment: @AndrewAngell i just found a link https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1998&viewlocale=en_US and i have try this url: **https://SHA2-test-api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token** in my code on my live server and its giving me response

Comment: That is an entirely separate topic.  The SSL certificate that's referring to has nothing to do with "sslv3" that you're seeing in the error message.  Stop refusing my answer and update your server.  This error will then go away.  Or don't and keep pulling your hair out.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with stamps.com API and in our case at the time of this post the solution was to set the `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` to `5`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 5);
```

Comment: No...5 wouldn't work.  5 would use TLS 1.1.  You need 6, which is for TLS 1.2.